shellcode simulating buffer overflow
Here is a snippet of a shellcode that i have from a course i am taking
it claims simulate a buffer overflow
I am not clear how it works
section .data
    payload db 'This is the payload of the exploit.'

section .bss
    buffer resb 64  ; Buffer to overflow

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    ; Shellcode to execute /bin/sh
    jmp short shellcode
    nop

exploit:
    ; Your payload goes here
    mov eax, 4           ; syscall: sys_write
    mov ebx, 1           ; file descriptor: stdout
    mov ecx, payload     ; pointer to the payload
    mov edx, 30          ; length of the payload
    int 0x80             ; interrupt to invoke syscall

    ; Exit the program
    mov eax, 1           ; syscall: sys_exit
    xor ebx, ebx         ; exit code 0
    int 0x80             ; interrupt to invoke syscall

shellcode:
    call exploit
    db 'Hello, world!'    ; Actual payload
    ; Buffer overflow to overwrite the return address
    ; Add padding to reach the return address
    times 64 - ($ - $$) db 0
    ; Overwrite the return address with the beginning of the shellcode
    dd shellcode

I see when we execute
call   exploit
the return address on the stack is the address of
db 'Hello World'
After this is have no idea what can happen since these are not instructions
these are data related commands
So what happens when the processor sees this.
I have tried single stepping in gdb  of course it does not do what it claims :)
but still want to understand what happens after call returns  what i can do to make it work.

Hint: What’s the last thing the “exploit” call does?

The  exploit call first makes the sys_write syscall then when it returns  AFAIK has to return to the db 'Hello World' address ,
by single stepping in gdb i see   that it executes the sys_exit call  is done
also not that i want you to give me the answer easily ,  i am willing to work for it :)
just want to say this is NOT a graded course/certification course   etc
it is a course on udemy   a Assembly refresher course    & i think  at the moment not feeling refreshed.

When i see the .data section in gdb
it is just 35 bytes  long  (maint info sections)
so  though i do see times is within .text
it is stil a  varaible right
but gdb has no clue what .times is ?

After is the exit system call is invoked, the program will exit.  So, the function will never return.

True , what i mean is  the claim of this shellcode is that the stuff
after call exploit  instruction will overwrite return address on the stack causing it to infinetly keep executing exploit & in fact never execute the exit  & that i do not see
The shellcode as given i do not even see that need for all the variables like
times. dd shell code etc

This code is just a weird way to print the payload string. There's no exploit or anything here. After all, all the buffers are in the "heap". Also no buffer is written. Probably they meant to show how a shellcode is structured, but failed hard. Since you find this on udemy I wouldn't expect anything better. Simply put: ask for a refund on the basis that their material is grossly wrong and learn assembly by yourself with the help of free resources online (see the x86 tag wiki and similar).

So are you saying this line  in the code is never evaluated
times 64 - ($ - $$) db 0
seems that is true from what i see
just curious what happens to these lines
i used objdump/readelf  even gdb does not
know when i say
p times
so what is nasm doing with those lines of code :)
